# display events only on onclick of the day of events

Tags: javascript

I have this code im using to display events from a calendar but its displaying ALL of the events for that month and I only want to display the events for the day when a user clicks on a certain day. For example, click on February 10, you get all of the events for that day.

```
        var eventList = $('<div/>').addClass('c-event-list');

        for (var i = 0; i < settings.events.length; i++) {
            var d = settings.events[i].datetime;

            if ((d.getMonth() - 1) == dMonth && d.getFullYear() == dYear) {
                var date = lpad(d.getMonth(), 2) + '/' +
                           lpad(d.getDate(), 2) + ' ' +
                           lpad(d.getHours() %12, 2) + ':' +
                           lpad(d.getMinutes(), 2);
                var item = $('<div/>').addClass('c-event-item');
                var title = $('<div/>')
                             .addClass('title')
                             .html(date + '  ' + settings.events[i].title + '<br />');
                var description = $('<div/>')
                                   .addClass('description')
                                   .html(settings.events[i].description + '<br />');

                item.attr('data-event-day', d.getDate());
                item.on('mouseover', mouseOverItem).on('mouseleave', mouseLeaveItem);
                item.append(title).append(description);
                eventList.append(item);
            }
       }

       $(instance).addClass('calendar');
       cEventsBody.append(eventList);
       $(instance).html(cBody).append(cEvents);
    }

    return print();
}
```

Thanks in advance for any assistance.

Comment: There is some code missing. What do lpad and print exactly? What is this settings-object?

Comment: This code is unintelligible without viewing all the calls to each function and collective objects associated with the code. *Damnit, Harry! I'm not a wizard!*

Comment: function print() {
            loadEvents();
            var dWeekDayOfMonthStart = new Date(dYear, dMonth, 1).getDay();
            var dLastDayOfMonth = new Date(dYear, dMonth + 1, 0).getDate();
            var dLastDayOfPreviousMonth = new Date(dYear, dMonth + 1, 0).getDate() - dWeekDayOfMonthStart + 1;

Comment: Here is the other part:
            var cBody = $('<div/>').addClass('c-grid');
            var cEvents = $('<div/>').addClass('c-event-grid');
            var cEventsBody = $('<div/>').addClass('c-event-body');
            cEvents.append($('<div/>').addClass('c-event-title c-pad-top').html(settings.eventTitle));
            cEvents.append(cEventsBody);

Comment: this is the code from e-calendar and if I could post all of it somehow I would?  its not allowed as its too long....

Comment: You can view the code here   http://www.jqueryscript.net/time-clock/Create-A-Simple-Event-Calendar-with-jQuery-e-calendar.html

Comment: Please do not overlook the "Show code snippet"-section :) , within this there is a practical example of what you have requested in one of your last comments. After scrolling down there is a "Run code snippet"-Button. Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

What I can see from your code is that this condition determines the month and year that events should be held on:

```
((d.getMonth() - 1) == dMonth && d.getFullYear() == dYear)
```

So when you want to display events only on a certain day you have to extend this condition like:

```
(d.getDate() == dDay && (d.getMonth() - 1) == dMonth && d.getFullYear() == dYear)
```

dDay is a new varibale that holds the day that events should be held on.

Comment: ok so if the variables are already declared in the document like this:

Comment: var eCalendar = function (options, object) {
        // Initializing global variables
        var adDay = new Date().getDate();
        var adMonth = new Date().getMonth();
        var adYear = new Date().getFullYear();
        var dDay = adDay;
        var dMonth = adMonth;
        var dYear = adYear;
        var instance = object;
I should be good to go with that?

Comment: dDay must be declared in the document. where are dMonth and dYear declared?

Comment: it's not readable to post code within comment-fields. please stop that.

Comment: Let's just test this. Define dDay where dMonth and DYear are defined and assign it with 12. Let's see whether events on day 12 are displayed only.

Comment: No problem, there is no ticking clock. one step in a while.

Comment: NOPE.  now my calendar doesnt display at all.

Comment: is an error thrown? are there events that are held on 12th day? In your developer console there you should be informed when an error occured.

Comment: I put the code back in the way it was so now it works again but still not able to display days.  I didnt use a developer console so I will try this there and see what I get.

Comment: After looking at an example: http://www.jqueryscript.net/demo/Create-A-Simple-Event-Calendar-with-jQuery-e-calendar/ This condition really determines what events are displayed and when. But unfortunately this plugin does not seem to work as you want it to be.

Comment: Do you know of anything that would work the way I want it to or where I could find it?

Comment: How could I have it write "no events" if there are no events in that month?

Comment: You can to have this plugin show "no events" when there are none. But as far as I can see you have to modify this plugin so that it reacts in this way.

Answer (score 0):

Following your request within last answer to show "no events" when a month is selected and there are none available.

I have modified this plugin so that it shows a "text"(for instance "no events") when the list on the right side is empty. I have tested it and it works.

This modification is ok because it is MIT licensed.

```js
(function($) {

  var eCalendar = function(options, object) {
    // Initializing global variables
    var adDay = new Date().getDate();
    var adMonth = new Date().getMonth();
    var adYear = new Date().getFullYear();
    var dDay = adDay;
    var dMonth = adMonth;
    var dYear = adYear;
    var instance = object;

    var settings = $.extend({}, $.fn.eCalendar.defaults, options);

    function lpad(value, length, pad) {
      if (typeof pad == 'undefined') {
        pad = '0';
      }
      var p;
      for (var i = 0; i < length; i++) {
        p += pad;
      }
      return (p + value).slice(-length);
    }

    var mouseOver = function() {
      $(this).addClass('c-nav-btn-over');
    };
    var mouseLeave = function() {
      $(this).removeClass('c-nav-btn-over');
    };
    var mouseOverEvent = function() {
      $(this).addClass('c-event-over');
      var d = $(this).attr('data-event-day');
      $('div.c-event-item[data-event-day="' + d + '"]').addClass('c-event-over');
    };
    var mouseLeaveEvent = function() {
      $(this).removeClass('c-event-over')
      var d = $(this).attr('data-event-day');
      $('div.c-event-item[data-event-day="' + d + '"]').removeClass('c-event-over');
    };
    var mouseOverItem = function() {
      $(this).addClass('c-event-over');
      var d = $(this).attr('data-event-day');
      $('div.c-event[data-event-day="' + d + '"]').addClass('c-event-over');
    };
    var mouseLeaveItem = function() {
      $(this).removeClass('c-event-over')
      var d = $(this).attr('data-event-day');
      $('div.c-event[data-event-day="' + d + '"]').removeClass('c-event-over');
    };
    var nextMonth = function() {
      if (dMonth < 11) {
        dMonth++;
      } else {
        dMonth = 0;
        dYear++;
      }
      print();
    };
    var previousMonth = function() {
      if (dMonth > 0) {
        dMonth--;
      } else {
        dMonth = 11;
        dYear--;
      }
      print();
    };

    var checkEventsOnCurrentMonth = function() {

      var eventNum = $('.c-event-list').find('.c-event-item') ? $('.c-event-list').find('.c-event-item').length : 0;
      if (!eventNum) {
        $('.c-event-list').html($.fn.eCalendar.defaults.noEventText);
      }

    };

    function loadEvents() {
      if (typeof settings.url != 'undefined' && settings.url != '') {
        $.ajax({
          url: settings.url,
          async: false,
          success: function(result) {
            settings.events = result;
          }
        });
      }
    }

    function print() {
      loadEvents();
      var dWeekDayOfMonthStart = new Date(dYear, dMonth, 1).getDay();
      var dLastDayOfMonth = new Date(dYear, dMonth + 1, 0).getDate();
      var dLastDayOfPreviousMonth = new Date(dYear, dMonth + 1, 0).getDate() - dWeekDayOfMonthStart + 1;

      var cBody = $('<div/>').addClass('c-grid');
      var cEvents = $('<div/>').addClass('c-event-grid');
      var cEventsBody = $('<div/>').addClass('c-event-body');
      cEvents.append($('<div/>').addClass('c-event-title c-pad-top').html(settings.eventTitle));
      cEvents.append(cEventsBody);
      var cNext = $('<div/>').addClass('c-next c-grid-title c-pad-top');
      var cMonth = $('<div/>').addClass('c-month c-grid-title c-pad-top');
      var cPrevious = $('<div/>').addClass('c-previous c-grid-title c-pad-top');
      cPrevious.html(settings.textArrows.previous);
      cMonth.html(settings.months[dMonth] + ' ' + dYear);
      cNext.html(settings.textArrows.next);

      cPrevious.on('mouseover', mouseOver).on('mouseleave', mouseLeave).on('click', previousMonth);
      cNext.on('mouseover', mouseOver).on('mouseleave', mouseLeave).on('click', nextMonth);

      cBody.append(cPrevious);
      cBody.append(cMonth);
      cBody.append(cNext);
      for (var i = 0; i < settings.weekDays.length; i++) {
        var cWeekDay = $('<div/>').addClass('c-week-day c-pad-top');
        cWeekDay.html(settings.weekDays[i]);
        cBody.append(cWeekDay);
      }
      var day = 1;
      var dayOfNextMonth = 1;
      for (var i = 0; i < 42; i++) {
        var cDay = $('<div/>');
        if (i < dWeekDayOfMonthStart) {
          cDay.addClass('c-day-previous-month c-pad-top');
          cDay.html(dLastDayOfPreviousMonth++);
        } else if (day <= dLastDayOfMonth) {
          cDay.addClass('c-day c-pad-top');
          if (day == dDay && adMonth == dMonth && adYear == dYear) {
            cDay.addClass('c-today');
          }
          for (var j = 0; j < settings.events.length; j++) {
            var d = settings.events[j].datetime;
            if (d.getDate() == day && (d.getMonth() - 1) == dMonth && d.getFullYear() == dYear) {
              cDay.addClass('c-event').attr('data-event-day', d.getDate());
              cDay.on('mouseover', mouseOverEvent).on('mouseleave', mouseLeaveEvent);
            }
          }
          cDay.html(day++);
        } else {
          cDay.addClass('c-day-next-month c-pad-top');
          cDay.html(dayOfNextMonth++);
        }
        cBody.append(cDay);
      }
      var eventList = $('<div/>').addClass('c-event-list');
      for (var i = 0; i < settings.events.length; i++) {
        var d = settings.events[i].datetime;
        if ((d.getMonth() - 1) == dMonth && d.getFullYear() == dYear) {
          var date = lpad(d.getDate(), 2) + '/' + lpad(d.getMonth(), 2) + ' ' + lpad(d.getHours(), 2) + ':' + lpad(d.getMinutes(), 2);
          var item = $('<div/>').addClass('c-event-item');
          var title = $('<div/>').addClass('title').html(date + '  ' + settings.events[i].title + '<br/>');
          var description = $('<div/>').addClass('description').html(settings.events[i].description + '<br/>');
          item.attr('data-event-day', d.getDate());
          item.on('mouseover', mouseOverItem).on('mouseleave', mouseLeaveItem);
          item.append(title).append(description);
          eventList.append(item);
        }
      }
      $(instance).addClass('calendar');
      cEventsBody.append(eventList);
      $(instance).html(cBody).append(cEvents);

      checkEventsOnCurrentMonth();

    }

    return print();
  }

  $.fn.eCalendar = function(oInit) {
    return this.each(function() {
      return eCalendar(oInit, $(this));
    });
  };

  // plugin defaults
  $.fn.eCalendar.defaults = {
    weekDays: ['Dom', 'Seg', 'Ter', 'Qua', 'Qui', 'Sex', 'Sab'],
    months: ['Janeiro', 'Fevereiro', 'Março', 'Abril', 'Maio', 'Junho', 'Julho', 'Agosto', 'Setembro', 'Outubro', 'Novembro', 'Dezembro'],
    textArrows: {
      previous: '<',
      next: '>'
    },
    eventTitle: 'Eventos',
    noEventText: 'no events',
    url: '',
    events: [{
      title: 'Brasil x Croácia',
      description: 'Abertura da copa do mundo 2014',
      datetime: new Date(2014, 6, 12, 17)
    }, {
      title: 'Brasil x México',
      description: 'Segundo jogo da seleção brasileira',
      datetime: new Date(2014, 6, 17, 16)
    }, {
      title: 'Brasil x Camarões',
      description: 'Terceiro jogo da seleção brasileira',
      datetime: new Date(2014, 6, 23, 16)
    }]
  };

}(jQuery));
```

```css
.calendar * {

  box-sizing: border-box;

  font-family: Tahoma;

  font-size: 14px;

}

.calendar-sm {

  cursor: default;

  width: 800px;

  height: 370px;

}

.calendar {

  cursor: default;

  width: 600px;

  height: 270px;

}

.calendar-sm .c-pad-top {

  padding-top: 2%;

}

.calendar .c-pad-top {

  padding-top: 3%;

}

.c-grid {

  box-shadow: 2px 2px 5px #888888;

  height: inherit;

}

.c-day {

  width: 14.28%;

  height: 13%;

  background-color: #EFF4F9;

  float: left;

  text-align: center;

}

.c-day-previous-month {

  width: 14.28%;

  height: 13%;

  background-color: #F9FBFD;

  float: left;

  text-align: center;

  color: gray;

}

.c-day-next-month {

  width: 14.28%;

  height: 13%;

  background-color: #F9FBFD;

  float: left;

  text-align: center;

  color: gray;

}

.c-week-day {

  width: 14.28%;

  height: 10.38%;

  background-color: rgb(145, 172, 203);

  color: white;

  float: left;

  text-align: center;

  font-weight: bold;

  padding-top: 1%;

}

.c-next {

  width: 12.5%;

  height: 12%;

  padding: 2% 2% 0 2%;

  text-align: right;

  cursor: pointer;

}

.c-previous {

  width: 12.5%;

  height: 12%;

  padding: 2% 2% 0 2%;

  text-align: left;

  cursor: pointer;

}

.c-month {

  width: 75%;

  height: 12%;

  text-align: center;

}

.c-nav-btn-over {

  background-color: rgb(137, 163, 192) !important;

  font-weight: bold;

}

.c-today {

  background-color: #D8EAF1;

}

.c-event {

  background-color: rgb(166, 166, 166);

  color: white;

  font-weight: bold;

  cursor: pointer;

}

.c-grid {

  float: left;

  width: 50%;

}

.c-event-grid {

  margin-left: 1px;

  height: inherit;

  width: 49%;

  float: left;

  box-shadow: 2px 2px 5px #888888;

}

.c-grid-title {

  font-weight: bold;

  float: left;

  background-color: rgb(112, 145, 183);

  color: white;

}

.c-event-title {

  width: 100%;

  height: 12%;

  text-align: center;

  font-weight: bold;

  background-color: rgb(135, 155, 188);

  color: white;

}

.c-event-body {

  background-color: #EFF4F9;

  height: 88.1%;

}

.c-event-list {

  padding: 7 0 0 0;

  overflow: auto;

  height: 95%;

}

.c-event-item > .title {

  font-weight: bold;

}

.c-event-item > div {

  text-overflow: ellipsis;

  width: inherit;

  overflow: hidden;

  white-space: nowrap;

}

.c-event-item {

  padding-left: 10px;

  margin-bottom: 10px;

}

.c-event-over {

  background-color: lightgray;

  font-weight: bold;

  color: black;

}

.c-event-over > .description {

  font-weight: normal;

}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head lang="en">
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>jQuery e-calendar Plugin Demo</title>
  <link href="http://www.jqueryscript.net/css/jquerysctipttop.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
  <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="../js/jquery.e-calendar.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="index.js"></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="../css/jquery.e-calendar.css" />
</head>

<body>
  <div id="jquery-script-menu">
    <div class="jquery-script-center">
      <ul>
        <li><a href="http://www.jqueryscript.net/time-clock/Create-A-Simple-Event-Calendar-with-jQuery-e-calendar.html">Download This Plugin</a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="http://www.jqueryscript.net/">Back To jQueryScript.Net</a>
        </li>
      </ul>
      <div class="jquery-script-ads">
        <script type="text/javascript">
          <!--
          google_ad_client = "ca-pub-2783044520727903";
          /* jQuery_demo */
          google_ad_slot = "2780937993";
          google_ad_width = 728;
          google_ad_height = 90;
           //-->
        </script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="http://pagead2.googlesyndication.com/pagead/show_ads.js">
        </script>
      </div>
      <div class="jquery-script-clear"></div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <h1 style="margin-top:150px;">jQuery e-calendar Plugin Demo</h1>
  <div id="calendar"></div>
</body>
<script type="text/javascript">
  var _gaq = _gaq || [];
  _gaq.push(['_setAccount', 'UA-36251023-1']);
  _gaq.push(['_setDomainName', 'jqueryscript.net']);
  _gaq.push(['_trackPageview']);

  (function() {
    var ga = document.createElement('script');
    ga.type = 'text/javascript';
    ga.async = true;
    ga.src = ('https:' == document.location.protocol ? 'https://ssl' : 'http://www') + '.google-analytics.com/ga.js';
    var s = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0];
    s.parentNode.insertBefore(ga, s);
  })();
</script>
<script>
  $(document).ready(function() {

    $.fn.eCalendar.defaults.noEventText = '<br/>there are no events available';

    $('#calendar').eCalendar({

      weekDays: ['Sun', 'Mon', 'Tue', 'Wed', 'Thu', 'Fri', 'Sat'],
      months: ['January', 'February', 'March', 'April', 'May', 'June', 'July', 'August', 'September', 'October', 'November', 'December'],
      textArrows: {
        previous: '<',
        next: '>'
      },
      eventTitle: 'Events',
      url: '',
      events: [{
        title: 'Event 1',
        description: 'Description 1',
        datetime: new Date(2014, 7, 15, 17)
      }, {
        title: 'Event 2',
        description: 'Description 2',
        datetime: new Date(2014, 7, 14, 16)
      }, {
        title: 'Event 3',
        description: 'jQueryScript.Net',
        datetime: new Date(2014, 7, 10, 16)
      }]
    });
  });
</script>

</html>
```

This is the function that check whether the event-list is empty and show a text if it's true. Put this function after previousMonth-function or somewhere within the library:

```
var checkEventsOnCurrentMonth = function(){

    var eventNum = $('.c-event-list').find('.c-event-item') ? $('.c-event-list').find('.c-event-item').length : 0;
    if(!eventNum){
       $('.c-event-list').html('no events');
    }

};
```

This function you have to call at the end of print:

```
function print() { 

      ...
      ...
      ...
      $(instance).addClass('calendar');
      cEventsBody.append(eventList);
      $(instance).html(cBody).append(cEvents);

      // this is the function you have to call at the end of print:
      checkEventsOnCurrentMonth();

}
```

Furthermore you can define the text in another fashion.
There are default values or settings at the bottom of the library.

```
$.fn.eCalendar.defaults = {
    weekDays: ['Dom', 'Seg', 'Ter', 'Qua', 'Qui', 'Sex', 'Sab'],
    ...
    ...
    noEventText: 'no events',
    ...
    ...
};
```

I've defined a new property "noEventText" to be used as text when no events are available.

The function checkEventsOnCurrentMonth  has to be altered for this new default-value(noEventText) to be taken into consideration:

```
    var checkEventsOnCurrentMonth = function(){

        var eventNum = $('.c-event-list').find('.c-event-item') ? $('.c-event-list').find('.c-event-item').length : 0;
        if(!eventNum){
           $('.c-event-list').html($.fn.eCalendar.defaults.noEventText);
        }

    };
```

At the end you can define the text before the plugin has been started:

```
    $(document).ready(function () {
         // here you can define the text and put some html into it.
         $.fn.eCalendar.defaults.noEventText = 'there are no events available';

         $('#calendar').eCalendar({
            ...
            ...
         });
    });
```

As mentioned I've tested it but only with the download-version you can find here: http://www.jqueryscript.net/time-clock/Create-A-Simple-Event-Calendar-with-jQuery-e-calendar.html

Image:

[image]

Comment: I've included a whole example by stackoverflow's new code-snippet functionality, I didn't know it before ;) You have to click until July 2014 to show some events.